# numpy pairwise vectorized logic

Tags: python, numpy

lets say I have two numpy arrays described by the matrices:

```
a = [["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"],["g","h","i"]]
b = [[False,False,False],[True,False,False],[False,True,True]]
```

And I want to compute a matrix equivalent to:

```
[[None,None,None],["d",None,None],[None,"h","i"]]
```

With a function:

```
f(x,y) = x if y else None
```

Where x is the value in the first matrix at location (i,j) and y is the value in the second matrix at location (i,j)

I thought maybe I could do something like this:

```
c = a if b else None
```

But doesn't work, any thoughts? Numpy arrays seem to readily support 2D vectorized mathematical functions, but not necessarily logical operations...

Comment: `if/else` is python logic, without any implied loop or 'vectorization'.  It isn't an 'operator', so can't be overloaded.

Comment: interesting good point, ````a if b else c```` is called a ternary operator, but I guess it isn't really an operator

Comment: It's an operator in the sense that it produces a value, and the arguments are in-line.  It's a special syntactic construction.  The interpreter probably does translate it to a function call, but as far as I know it's not available for redefinition in user defined classes.  Expressions like 'x+y' are implemented as `x.__add__(y)` calls, using a `x` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `np.where()` does precisely what you need:

```
np.where(b, a, None)
#array([[None, None, None],
#       ['d', None, None],
#       [None, 'h', 'i']], dtype=object)
```